# SpringMVC: Adding a mediatype to static resources to be served

Tags: spring-mvc, staticresource

in my spring-mvc application I'm serving some static resources. JavaScrips, CSS and images get served correctly but there are also some json files which not get delivered.

So this file I can see in the browser:
http://localhost:8080/path/to/resources/example.png

But this file (which is in the same directory) I don't receive:
http://localhost:8080/path/to/resources/example.json

I'm getting this:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No media type found for ServletContext resource [/resources/path/to/resources/example.json] - returning 404
```

So I would assume that I need to add somewhere this mediatype extension (.json) in the configuration but I can't find it.

Help please!

Comment: Can you share the static resource configuration in your applications? The `<mvc:resource ...>` configurations

Comment: <resources mapping="/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: Have you enabled `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your configuration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this on your web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>json</extension>
    <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks! Took awhile to find this answer, but it worked for me too. In my case, all I was getting was a 404.